# Autenticar usuários através de um formulário com conexão a banco de dados é seguro com relação a crackers?

Tags: sql-server, delphi, cracker

Gostaria de autenticar os usuários do meu programa usando um formulário com conexão a um banco de dados sql server mas não sei se é uma forma segura contra cópias não autorizadas.
A autenticação será feita de forma comum com nome de usuário e senha, o programa fará uma checagem dos dados no banco de dados e validará o acesso ao programa.

Gostaria de saber se é seguro ou preciso tomar alguns cuidados para evitar este tipo de problema ?

Uso Delphi XE5 e Sql Server 2012.

Comment: Lembre-se de estabelecer conexão "segura" entre o aplicativo e o computador onde está o banco de dados.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nestes casos, é importante que não somente seu programa esteja bem amarrado na validação de senha no banco de dados, mas que também a senha esteja criptografada. Há muitos casos no mercado de grandes softwares que utilizam tal método e até então não tiveram problemas com crackers.

É interessante também inserir validações em seu software para verificar se alguém está tentando por força bruta realizar a quebra de determinada senha, como por exemplo determinar uma quantidade máxima de tentativas erradas simultâneas em um determinado dia.

Em todo caso, o método de comparação de login e senha para acesso é utilizado pela grande maioria dos softwares de mercado desenvolvidos em Delphi.

Answer (score 0):

A senha não pode ser 'crua', ou seja, não pode se comportar como o nome de usuário, sendo uma string pura.
Você precisa criptografar.

Existem funções simples para isso.
Como AES, já resolve.
Porém pode usar hash... sha1, md5, etc.

md5 foi quebrado, mas... aes também quebra com brute-force. 
A princípio para estudo, qualquer uma serve. Depois você pode fazer testes e aprimorar. 
Limitar tentativas (q evitaria o caso do brute-force) etc.

Answer (score 0):

É um método que pode ser utilizado, desde que não deixe a senha trafegar em texto pleno pela rede, ou salvá-la assim no banco de dados.

O ideal é, ao capturar a senha do usuário, criptografá-la pelo programa e enviá-la ao banco de dados criptografada. Para validar a senha na hora do login, faça o mesmo processo: criptografe a senha informada e envie para o banco de dados checar. Se o MD5/SHA1 for o mesmo salvo no BD, libera o acesso.